# Getting skew normal parameters from its moments

Tags: r, moments, skew-normal-distribution

I have data on expenditure in dollars, and for set of countries i know average expenditure, sd, skewness. For example in country A mean=200\$, sd=100, skewness=1.5 and i want to estimate probability of spending below 100\$ in that country with skew normal distribution (with `psn` from R package `sn`). Is there a way to derive parameters of skew normal distribution(location, scale, shape) if i know mean, sd and skewness of original scale of the data in \$? Wikipedia has moments represented in terms of parameters of distribution, but i think i need the opposite way (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution). Can someone confirm using psn in this way is wrong:

```
psn(100,200,100,1.5)
```

Comment: This involves solving a system of algebraic equations of up to the third degree, whence the answer can be found in terms of roots of cubic polynomials.  A general answer is very messy to write--it would take about a page of equations--and is potentially numerically unstable, so the best practical solution is likely to solve the equations numerically.

Comment: You can find many examples here by an appropriate search.  Because there are so many, this one narrows it to upvoted answers: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=numerical+solution+%5Br%5D+score%3A1+is%3Aanswer.  AFAIK, `R` does not have a routine for solving simultaneous nonlinear equations--but that's no problem, because such solutions can be obtained as the *minimizers* of any nicely-behaved function that expresses how far apart the values are.  Use `optim` for that purpose.